# how to work with big flutter project contains git submodules

Tags: flutter, git, dart

In general, I know how to work with git submodules and recursive cloning and pulling.
but once I moved to flutter many questions have been raised and could not find clear answers, if you guys please can help:

- should the submodule be a flutter project as well ?
- does it have its own pubspec.yml ? if so, should I always make sure they are aligned with versions ? what if same package used in submodule and parent module ?
- does flutter pub get required in each module then ? or the running it on top level will do it recursively ??
- must submodules have same structure of lib/main.dart and so on ? can't make it as directories only ? can lib/main.dart be removed ?
- in my case submodules are not sub-applications, only contains common code between multiple applications, but flutter project itself is considered as application, right ? will there be any conflicts ?
- I'm aware of flutter package, but in my case, I preferred working with submodule instead

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, there aren't a lot of "easy ways" to modularize a Flutter project easily.

If you want to do it "vanilla", you should export the modules of your code as libraries, and add it to your project as dependencies.
[You can find a example here](https://github.com/rrifafauzikomara/flutter_modularization/tree/local)

If you want to do it in a more industrial way, there is a package called [melos](https://pub.dev/packages/melos) which help you build and manage your modules. This is pretty useful if you have a large codebase.

Those "modules" are behaving exactly as external libraries :

- In your modules, you can define tags, and your main application you can specify which tag to use.
- If you use a library like `Provider` in a module and in your main app, you could have some dependencies collision if you use different versions in the module and in the main app (would only happen if you have major versions diffs).
- Your submodule will be a library, meaning you won't have any `main.dart`, but it'll be a Flutter project with a dedicated `pubspec.yaml`.

If you've got a background of a Java/Kotlin/Android developer, you probably know that in a Native Android projects, the management of submodules is possible thanks to `gradle`. Because of Flutter's design, it's not possible to have the same "native" behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! I will keep the packages as last option. I wanted submodule because I wanted to keep it dynamic and keep changes in place, unlike  packages where I have to "release" push any change I need so i will be reflected. In addition, hot reload does not work with packages changes. Thanks man, I will consider moving to packages